# Rearranging formula with brackets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having some trouble with rearranging an equation. My memory of how to do them is hazy from school days so please forgive its probable simplicity.

From the following equation I need to make either $Q_a$ or $Q_m$ the focus of the equation.

$$110 - \frac{Q_m}{30}=50-\frac{Q_a}{90}$$

It does not matter which as they are part of a linear equation where $Q_a+Q_m=4000$ so the other can be calculated. This is my attempt but I am not sure if I am correct:

$\times 30:$

$$110 - Q_m = 1500 - \frac{Q_a}{90}$$

$\times 90:$

$$9900 - Q_m = 1500 - Q_a$$

$-1500:$

$$8400 - Q_m = Q_a.$$

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $(110 - \frac{Qm}{ 30})\times30 = (50 - \frac{Qa}{90})\times30$;

$110\times30-Qm=50\times30-\frac{Qa}{90}\times30$;

$3300-Qm=1500-\frac{Qa}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the same to both sides of the equation all the time. In the first step, you multiplied by $30$ every number except the $110$, and in the second step, you did the same, and this is wrong.

What I would do is first add or subtract all number terms so that the $Q_a$ or $Q_m$ terms are alone. For example:

$$110-\frac{Q_m}{30}=50-\frac{Q_a}{90}$$
$$-110\qquad\rightarrow \qquad-\frac{Q_m}{30}=-60-\frac{Q_a}{90}$$
Then multiply both sides by some number to get the $Q_m$ term alone:
$$\times-30\qquad\rightarrow \qquad Q_m=-30\left(-60-\frac{Q_a}{90}\right)=1800+\frac{Q_a}{3}$$
So you get:
$$Q_m=1800+\frac{Q_a}{3}$$